# Convert Relative Url to Absolute Url

Tags: sharepoint-online, url

I am uploading an image in a Rich text field and want to send that image via mail.

I have email template where I am using `body` tag to get `Image URL`.

The Image URL is relative and appended with some div and style at the beginning and end.

How can Convert the relative URL to absolute URL so that I can embed that in the body tag to send image as mail.

Comment: Can you describe how you're generating the email? The basic answer is to add the server URL to the relative URL to get an absolute URL -- but how you can do so depends entirely on how you're creating the email.

Comment: Do you have the option to make the field enhanced rich text so you can alter the html? Obviously if general users who don't know html need to be able to add images this wouldn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue.  I was using HTML to generate my email via workflow, and the images I used to embed in the body of the email were switching to the relative URL and breaking in the emails.

My fix was to run my URL through tinyURL or go.USA.gov.  That shortened URL was not recognized by SharePoint and my images showed up in my email.

Comment: Reminded me to answer my related question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/165165/prevent-re-writing-of-relative-links-in-mht-files